# JLabel and JCheckBox change space between them

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I created a checkbox and a label and I would like to reduce the space between them.

```
panoSaison = new JPanel();
        panoSaison.setBorder(new TitledBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TitledBorder.border"), 
                "Saison des pneus recherchés", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
        contentPane.add(panoSaison, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        gestSaison = new GridLayout(1,2,0,0);
        panoSaison.setLayout(gestSaison);

        hiver = new JLabel();
        hiver.setText("Hiver");
        ete = new JLabel();
        ete.setText("Été");
        boxHiver = new JCheckBox();
        boxEte = new JCheckBox();

        grpSaison = new ButtonGroup();
        grpSaison.add(boxHiver);
        grpSaison.add(boxEte);

        panoSaison.add(boxHiver);
        panoSaison.add(hiver);
        panoSaison.add(boxEte);
        panoSaison.add(ete);
```

}

Which code should I use to fix the size?

Thank you,

Comment: Java is NOT JavaScript. Don't use the JavaScript tag to mark the code. Use the `{}` button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `GridLayout`. A `GridLayout` makes each cell the same size.

Instead maybe you want to use a `GridBagLayout`. Then each cell will be the size of the largest cell in the column.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and working examples. The example shows how to add a component to a given cell. So you will basically need to create your own 2x2 grid and add each of the components to a particular cell in the grid.

The tutorial explains the basics of all the standard layout managers.